# Is this space normed or not?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

This particular question was part of my analysis assignment I was unable to prove / disprove it.

> Let $V$ denote the vector space of all sequences $a=(a_1 , a_2,...,a_n,...)$ of real numbers such that $\sum_{n\geq 1} 2^n |a_n|$ converges. Define ||.||: $V \to \mathbb{R}$ by $||a|| =\sum_{n\geq 1}2^n |a_n|$. Then is $V$ complete normed space or not.

There were four questions to be answered regarding $V$ . I have done 3 but unable to do this. I know about completely normed space but I was unable to do this . The  idea is to show that every sequence of sequence converges to a limit and that limit is to be constructed or guessed but I am unable to do it

Kindly guide on how this should be done

Comment: Is $\{a_n\}$ a finite sequence?

Comment: Sorry, but there are missing a few definitions to make this a *vector* space, e.g. addition of two sequences of different length..

Comment: Since it talks about convergence, I presume that $a$ is intended to vary over infinite sequences, and the terminating representation in the question is a mistake. In that case, $V$ is just $L^1(\Bbb N)$ in disguise.

Comment: @fantasie no its not i have edited it

Comment: @User Isn't this just an $L^1$-space over $\mathbb{N}$ with $2^n$ times the counting measure? By the way, for completeness you need that every _Cauchy_ sequence converges (not every sequence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $l_1=\{(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...): \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_n|<\infty\}$ and let $T:l_1\to V$ with
$$T(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n,...)=\bigl(\frac{1}{2}\alpha_1,\frac{1}{2^2}\alpha_2,...,\frac{1}{2^n}\alpha_n,...\bigr)$$

By the identity
$$||T(\alpha)||_V=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n|\frac{\alpha_n}{2^n}|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_n|=||\alpha||_{l_1}$$

$T$ is a well defined linear and bounded operator from $l_1$ to $V$. Now observe that $T^{-1}(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...)=(2x_1,2^2x_2,...,2^nx_n,...)$, which means that $T$ is one to one and onto.

Now, for $x=(x_n)_n \in V$ we have
$$||T^{-1}(x)||_{l_1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n|x_n|=||x||_V$$
which means that $T^{-1}$ is also bounded. Hence, $V$ and $l_1$ are isometrically isomorphic. Which means that $V$ is complete.

Answer (score 2):

Define a measure space as $(\mathbb N,\mu),$ where for any subset $E\subset \mathbb N,$

$$\mu(E)=\sum_{n\in E} 2^n.$$

Then $L^1(\mathbb N,\mu)$ is precisely the set $V$ you describe, with

$$\|a\|=\int_{\mathbb N} |a|\,d\mu =\|a\|_{L^1(\mathbb N,\mu)}.$$

Since every $L^1$ space is a complete normed linear space, we are done.

Of course, if you haven't studied measure theory, the above is not too useful for this problem. But it's still worth knowing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm giving a more basic proof (considering the first two answers). The technique I'm using is rather standard and tries to infer global convergence of a Cauchy family of sequences by analyzing some sort of *vertical convergence* given componentwise. Let's first prove that  $(V, \| \cdot \|)$ is a normed space. This means that we have to prove first that $\| \cdot \|$ is, in fact, a norm:

1. Let $a \in V$, if $a \equiv 0$ then $\| a \| = 0$. On the other hand, if $\| a \| = 0$ we can infer that $a \equiv 0$, because otherwise we'll have $a_k \neq 0$ for some $k$ and thus $|a_k| > 0$ which for instance means $\sum_n {2^n} |a_n| \geq {2^k} | a_k| > 0$, a contradiction. The fact that $\| a \| \geq 0$ for all $a \in V$ is trivial. With what we prove, we also have $\| a \| = 0$ iff $a \equiv 0$.
2. Let $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ by the fact that  $| \beta a_k |
    = |\beta | |a_k|$ we have, that for any $a \in V$ $\| \beta a \| = | \beta | \| a \|$.  Where $\beta a = (\beta a_1, ..., \beta a_n, ... )$.
3. The triangle inequality follows the same logic. For, let $a, b \in V$ then, since $|a_k + b_k| \leq |a_k| + |b_k|$ (in the real line) then
   $\| a + b \| = \sum_k {2^k} | a_k + b_k| \leq \sum_k {2^k}(|a_k| + |b_k|)$
   We conclude with the fact that $\sum_k {2^k}|a_k|, \sum_k {2^k}|b_k| < \infty$.

The steps above ensure that $(V, |\ \cdot \|)$ is a normed space. We need to prove now that this space is **complete** and we are doing it the long way:

Let $\{a^{(n)}\}_n$ be a Cauchy sequence (sequence of sequences) in $(V, \| \cdot \|)$, here we denote the sequence $a^{(k)}$ by $a^{(k)} = (a_{k1}, a_{k2}, ..., a_{km}, ... )$. I see this kind of sequence as a neverending matrix with components given by $a_{ij}$, where we know that its rows tend to be very similar as we go downwards. The trick here is to find whether there is a way to describe the limit of those rows and then see if it lies in $(V, \| \cdot \|)$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, then there exists an $N_{\varepsilon} > 0$ such that for any $n,m > N_{\varepsilon}$ we have:

$$\| a^{(n)} - a^{(m)} \| 
< \varepsilon \implies \sum_k {2^k} |a_{nk} - a_{mk}| < \varepsilon$$

Which tell us ${2^k} | a_{nk} - a_{mk} | < \varepsilon$ for any $k \geq 1$. With this in mind, let's define the (vertical) sequences $\{ a_{nk}\}_n$ , and let $\varepsilon_0 > 0$, if we define $\varepsilon = \varepsilon_0 \cdot 2^k$ then, by the above result ($a^{(n)}$ being Cauchy), we have that there exists an $N_{\varepsilon} > 0$ such that for all $n,m > N_{\varepsilon}$ we have

$$| a_{nk} - a_{mk} | <  \varepsilon / 2^k = \varepsilon_0$$

as the above expression is true for any (fixed) $k$, we have that all sequences of the form  $\{ a_{nk}\}_n$ are Cauchy in $(\mathbb{R}, | \cdot |)$ and thus convergent. We can now define the (candidate vertical limit) sequence $b = (b_1, b_2, ..., b_n, ... )$ where $b_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{nk}$. If we manage to prove that $b \in V$ then we finally have that the space is complete.

Let's check if $b \in V$, for that we need $\| b \| < \infty$. In fact,

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\tag{$\star$}
\|b \| - \| a^{(n)} \| \leq \| b - a^{(n)} \|
\end{equation}

for each $n$, we can zoom in the last term to see

$$\| b - a^{(n)} \| = \sum_k 2^k | b_{k} - a_{nk} |$$

As $\{ a_{nk} \}_n$ converges to $b_k$ for any fixed $k$, we can take $\varepsilon_k = {1} / ({2^k \cdot k^2})$ and find an $N_k$, such that for any $n \geq N_k$, it happens that $2^k | b_{k} - a_{nk} | < 1 / k^2$. With this in mind, let's define $N_l = \sup_{k = 1,..., l} N_k$ and $S_l(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^l 2^k |b_k - a_{nk}|$, then

$$
S_l(N_l) = \sum_{k = 1}^l 2^k |b_k - a_{N_l k}| < \sum_{k=1}^{l} \frac{1}{k^2}
$$

By definition, the sequence $N_l$ is non decreasing in $l$, if it's bounded, then there exists an $N$ such that for any $n \geq N$; $\| b - a^{(n)} \| = \lim_{l \to \infty} S_l(n) <  \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{1}{2^k} < \infty$. On the other hand, if $N_l$ is not bounded, then as $\lim_{l \to \infty } N_l = \infty$ we substitute $l$ by $N_l$ finding that:
$$
\lim_{N_l \to \infty} \| b - a_{N_l} \| = \lim_{N_l \to \infty} S_{N_l}(N_l) < \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k^2} < \infty
$$

Then there exists an $N > 0$ such that,
$$
\| b - a^{(N)} \| < \infty
$$

We conclude using \ref{eq:1}.